# Solve a parametered function equation

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-equations

I can't figure out how to solve: $\forall t \in [0,1]$, $f((1-t)x+ty)=(1-t)f(x)+tf(y)$. I have proved that $f(0)=0$.

Comment: $ f(x)=ax+b $ is a solution.

Comment: Your function is both convex and concave so must be linear